# Declared types and Actual types

Tags: java

I understand that when creating a new object such as this:

```
GeomObject tri = new Triangle();
```

is more general and allows for more resuability, but what happens when tri is created like this:

```
Triangle tri = new Triangle();
```

Since Triangle is a subclass of GeomObject, isn't tri still a GeomObject? How does the declared type affect compilation? Thanks

*add: An additional question: say I have

```
Integer n1 = new Integer(3);
Object n2 = new Integer(4); 
System.out.println(n1.compareTo(n2));
```

I tried this out on Eclipse and I got errors even if I reversed n1 with n2. I thought that n2.compareTo(n1) would work because it would call the Object compareTo method and since Integer is an instance of object, it would be passable, but this is not the case. Could you explain this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Since `Triangle` is a subclass of `GeomObject`, isn't `tri` still a `GeomObject`?

Yes it is. Use the `instanceof` operator to test this:

```
System.out.println( (tri instanceof Triangl) ); //prints true
System.out.println( (tri instanceof GeomObject) ); //prints true
System.out.println( (tri instanceof Object) ); //prints true because every class extends from Object
```

> How does the declared type affect compilation?

It won't affect in any matter, just will make your code *inflexible* in case you need to use another implementation of `GeomObject` that is not a `Triangle`.

More info:

- [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

---

> I thought that `n2.compareTo(n1)` would work because it would call `Object#compareTo` method

This is incorrect since [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#method_summary) class doesn't have a `compareTo` method.

On the other hand, `n1.compareTo(n2)` won't work since you're passing an `Object` to the `compareTo` method when [`Integer#compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo(java.lang.Integer)) receives another `Integer` class type.

Note that when declaring this:

```
Object n2 = new Integer(4);
```

- The variable type will be **`Object`**, no matter if you initialize it as `Integer` or another class e.g. `String`.
- Only the overridden methods will behave as defined in the object reference run time type, this means if your `n2` variable holds an `Integer`, only the methods overridden in class `Integer` from class `Object` will behave as defined in the `Integer` class, all the other methods, fields, even the variable itself will behave as `Object`. In case of `Integer` class, these methods are [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), [`hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode()) and [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString()).
- The link provided above: *What does it mean to "program to an interface"?* explains the benefits of using an interface (or abstract class or a generic class) to generalize the work through generic interfaces/classes instead of direct implementation. Note that there are cases where this approach **won't apply** e.g. your current example using `Object` when you should use `Integer`. Note that `Object` class is *way too* generic (at least for this case), so I won't recommend using `Object` directly at least that you understand what you're really doing.

Comment: added more to the original question*

Comment: @xheyhenry please edit your question accordingly and **add* (do not remove anything) the new part of the question, then I'll edit my answer.